# Combine multiple select field values into a single variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an HTML form with multiple select dropdowns (most of the jQuery snippets I've found online talk about multi-selects which are different, i.e. checkboxes.)

How can you use jQuery to collect/join the values from all the dropdown fields, and separate them with a symbol i.e. comma or plus sign? Then, send to URL (WordPress tag search).

I've tried this code and it doesn't work:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#submit").click(function() {
    var tags = $(".option").map(function() {
    return ($(this).text() == "") ? null : $(this).text(); // ignore default
        // return $(this).text(); // include all values
 }).join("+");
window.location = "<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/tag/" + tags;
return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

Here's the latest version, with `.get` added, still no luck:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#submit").click(function() {
    var tags = $(".option").map(function() {
    return ($(this).text() == "") ? null : $(this).text(); // ignore default
    // return $(this).text(); // include all values
 }).get().join("+");
window.location = "<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/tag/" + tags;
// return false; // tried this on and off
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No errors are given, it simply doesn't submit anywhere.

Comment: If I open the console, I'm get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error on the `.join("+")`. As mentioned below jQuery map returns a jQuery object, absent the join function, so slip `.get()` before join to return an array that can be `.join`'d.

Comment: Question, do you want EVERY option, or only SELECTED options?

Comment: Oops sorry, don't know how to check console. Yes, we want only selected options from the dropdowns. If a dropdown is left as default (blank value) then it should be ignored in the .get function. We did try adding .get to the .join but still no luck! =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things: 1) added `.get()` to get access to `.join()`, and 2) limited the return to only selected options that are not blank:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#submit").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var tags = $(".option").map(function() {
      return (this.selected && $(this).text() != "") ? $(this).text() : null;
  }).get().join("+");
  window.location = "<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/tag/" + tags;
  });
});
```

And for good measure, pulled in the event object and prevented the default action.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jKGP8/

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts. However, this still did not work >_<

Comment: Since the linked JSFiddle works fine, my first suspect is the PHP `home_url()` function. When you view the source of your page what do you see for `window.location = ...`?

Comment: Oops! I had the .option on parent select rather than on every single option in dropdown. After fixing that, and then using .val instead of .text (easier to use lowercase values while keeping user-friendly text) it finally worked. Thanks so much! I wish I could vote you up ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You should use get() in combination with jquery map function, otherwise you receive not just array but jQuery object

```
var tags = $(".option").map(function() {
return ($(this).text() == "") ? null : $(this).text(); // ignore default
}).get().join("+");
$("#result").html(tags);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tx8HT/

With on click you should just replace your old var tags = .. string with new tag calculation.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#submit").click(function() {
var tags = $("#form .option").map(function() {
return ($(this).text() == "") ? null : $(this).text(); // ignore default
}).get().join("+");
window.location.href = "<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/tag/" + tags;
return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very interesting. However we are trying to join the results on click (submit) of the form by redirecting to a new URL i.e. example.com/tag/one+two+three+four/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your jQuery selector is wrong, should be "option" rather than ".option" (your code is looking for elements with the class "option").  Also, this will concatenate all select option text values, not just the ones that the user has selected.  It is not clear if this is what you are after, but I thought I would give you a heads up.

Comment: Yes, we saw this as a solution online, adding a class to each select dropdown rather than unique IDs. Not sure if its the best way though.